# CRUD con PHP Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

No se que pasa que no me quieren funcionar los botones de editar y eliminar

[image: El error...]

Comment: En tu archivo .php tu concatenas la cadena "del-"  seguida del nombre del registro sin comillas. El intérprete de javascript piensa que estás sumando un identificador que no existe, la solución es agregar comillas al rededor del nombre del registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes un error en esta linea man

```
$("#del-"+ASD123).click().......
```

esto seria lo correcto..

```
$("#del-ASD123").click().......
```

Comment: Con tu solución ya me sale la confirmación para borrar "Estas seguro?" pero no elimina, ya me sale el error aqui: window.location="./php/eliminar.php?placa="+ASD123;

Comment: tienes ASD123 como una variable cuando no lo es  osea lo estas mandando como parametro no entindo que intentas hacer y esta seria la sintaxis correcta `window.location.href=""`

Comment: Ya me funcionó, gracias!